# Error with async await ( at least in my opinion ) - ExpressJS, MongoDB, NodeJS, multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

### This is my code in backend (ExpressJs, multer)

**Note: I used cors in server.js file and it working as I expected in previous route, but in this Register Admin route, the other error occurs**

```
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: './public/uploads/' });
const User = require('../models/user.model'); // User model

router.post('/admin/register', upload.single('avatar'),
    async (req, res) => {
        const avatar = req.file.path.slice(7);
        const user = {
            ...JSON.parse(req.body.user),
            avatar
        };



        // hapi/joi validate => 1
        const { error } = Validation.adminRegisterValidation(user);
        if (error) {
            return res.json({ error: error.details[0].message });
        }
        // validate from database => 2
        const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: user.email });
        if (emailExist) {
            return res.json({ error: 'Email already exist!' });
        }
        // hash the password => 3
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);

        const newUser = new User({
            ...user,
            admin: false,
            password: hashedPassword,
            sub_admin: true
        });

        try {
            await newUser.save();
            return res.json("Add user success!");
        } catch (err) {
            return res.json({ error: err });
        }
    }
);
```

> **If i turn 1,2,3 to comment, the user is added as I expected**

**This project in my Github** [Github](https://github.com/hanh040499/shoe-shop)

*- Front-end in file: src -> components -> dashboard -> user-dashboard -> CreateUser.js*

*- Backend in file: backend -> routes -> user.route.js*

**THIS IS MY ERROR IMAGE** [image]

Comment: What error do u get?

Comment: I added error image!

Comment: whats the error the server throws?

Comment: Server don't throw errors, When I got above error, server is restart :(

Comment: I can teamview if necessary

Comment: Who help me please! This stucked me 2 days, I can teamview now

Comment: if you comment out bcrypt does it work?

Comment: if I comment out bcrypt, It will work once. The second "Add user" will occur above error again

Comment: This is a big bug, so tks for watching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found two errors that might be causing your issue, not really sure if it will totally fix your issue, but will definitely get you close.

1) Remove `Max` length property from `user schema`

Right now you have `max` length of 30 for password in your `user Schema` but once you hash the password, hashed password can go beyond 30 characters.

You can click [here](https://github.com/hanh040499/shoe-shop/blob/master/backend/models/user.model.js#L20) to see what I'm talking about.

2) You need to remove `old password` in order to store the new `hashed password`

In this line of code you are using [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to include all the fields in `NewUser` object from `user` object, which already includes `password` that comes from your frontend

```
const newUser = new User({
        ...user,
        admin: false,
        password: hashedPassword,
        sub_admin: true
    });
```

This what causes `newUser` to have 2 password fields, to delete the old password after hashing do this

```
// hash the password => 3
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);

    delete user.password

    const newUser = new User({
        ...user,
        admin: false,
        password: hashedPassword,
        sub_admin: true
    });
```

This way you can set password to new `Hashed` one.

AS your error is very Generic It's almost impossible to DEBUG it, these are the few things I found very odd.

**As I said not really sure if it will fix your error but it might get you close**

Comment: OK, I found only an error around bcrypt hash password, if I remove things relate to bcrypt, my program will run as I expected

Comment: Tks Shivam Sood, my error fixed. The error occurs because first error that you mentioned